# to find the number of elments in $\vert\{A \in {F_4^{3\times 5}} \mid rk_{F_4}A=3 \}\vert$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, ring-homomorphism

let for all $A \in {K^{m \times n}}$ $$\phi_A:K^{n\times 1}\rightarrow K^{m\times 1}$$
$$x \mapsto Ax$$
and $\phi_A$ ist  a vectorspaceHomorphismus

and the Rang of $\phi_A$  is  defined as $ Im_{\phi_A}=rk_{\phi_A}= rkA$

The question is to find the number of elemenets in $\{A \in {F_4^{5\times 3}} \mid rk_{F_4}A=3 \} $

$\textbf{My idea}$

let let for all $A \in {K^{5 \times 3}}$ $$\phi_A:F_4^{3\times 1}\rightarrow F_4^{5\times 1}$$
i do know that  $dim({F_4^{3\times 1}})=kern_{\phi_A}+Im_{\phi_A}=3$

because of $Im_{\phi_A}=rk_{\phi_A}= rkA=3 \Rightarrow kern_{\phi_A}=0 \Rightarrow  \phi_A $is injective function.

$\vert\{A \in {F_4^{5\times 3}} \mid rk_{F_4}A=3 \}\vert \Leftrightarrow \vert\{A \in {F_4^{5\times 3}} \mid \phi_A \text{is injective function.}\}\vert  \Leftrightarrow \vert\{\phi_A \mid \phi_A \in MAP_{injective}({F_4^{3\times1}},{F_4^{5\times1}})\}\vert= \frac{\vert {F_4^{5\times1}}\vert!}{ {(\vert F_4^{5\times1}}\vert-\vert {F_4^{3\times1}}\vert)!}= \frac{4^5!}{(4^5-4^3)!}$

but the solution  does give an  other number  which  different  than mine , can you  please tell me where is my mistake , the  right  solution was $\textbf{1051807680}$

Comment: How do you know the number of injective maps is $(4^5)! / (4^5-4^3)! $ ?. Note also that the number of matrices in ${\mathbb{F}_4}^{5\times 3}$ should be far less than the number you obtained.

Comment: One major place where you erred: elements of $F_4^{5\times3}$ aren't _just_ injective functions from $F_4^3$ to $F_4^5$; they're _linear_ functions. This is where much of your massive overcounting comes from, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $A\in {\mathbb{F}_4}^{3\times 5}$, it has rank 3 if and only if all three rows are linearly independent.

There are $4^5-1$ ways to select the first row, where minus 1 comes from the zero vector. The second row should not be a multiple of the first, so there are $4^5-4$ choices. The third row should not be any linear combination of the first and second row, there are $4^5-4^2$ possibilities for that.

Thus the desired number is $(4^5-1)(4^5-4)(4^5-4^2) = 1051807680$.

Comment: yeah   thank  that  seems  pretty  clear  and  correct .
but  in $F_4^{3\times5}$ there is 5 rows , how can  i say to choose the other 2 linear dependent

Comment: then would  be  the result for A $\in F_4^{3\times 5}$  ;
$(4^3-1)(4^3-4)(4^3-4^2)*4^3 *4^3$  right  ?
Ps:  in your answer  A must  be in ${F_4^{5\times3 }}$

Comment: @Mohbenay   If we follow the same convention, ${\mathbb{F}_4}^{3\times 5}$ should have 3 rows and 5 columns. The number of rank 3 matrices for ${\mathbb{F}_4}^{3\times 5}$ and ${\mathbb{F}_4}^{5\times 3}$ are the same.

Comment: yeah i do know that ,  but  here i must find the number of A  that  have  rank 3 , so that  from  5 rows must be only 3 lineare independent , and the other 2 are linear combination from  the other 3 , and then  i can  create more A  
am i right ?